# How to produce collections of links within the Links section using Spring HATEOAS

Tags: java, json, spring-hateoas

I am attempting to produce a JSON output similar to the example below:

```
{
    "links": {
        "self": { "href": "http://api.com/items" },
        "item": [
            { "href": "http://api.com/items/1" },
            { "href": "http://api.com/items/2" }
        ]
    "data": [
            {"itemName":"a"}, 
            {"itemName":"b"} 
     ] 
}
```

Notice that `item` is the collection of linked objects. How would I go about doing that with Spring HATEOAS?

UPDATE:
Adding the same rel multiple times to my `UserResource` gives me the following:

```
"links": [
    {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sophia/users/admin"
    },
    {
        "rel": "item",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sophia/companies/01393048000170/item/1"
    },
    {
        "rel": "item",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sophia/companies/01393048000170/item/2"
    },
    {
        "rel": "item",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sophia/companies/01393048000170/item/3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add multiple links with the very same rel.

```
Resource resource = new Resource(data);
resource.add(new Link("…", "item"));
resource.add(new Link("…", "item"));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. This structure will only work on Resource then? I have a `UserResource` class which extends ResourceSupport and adding multiple links with the same rel does not give me a collection of the rel.

Comment: No, everything extending `ResourceSupport` will work. I just used `Resource` as a commonly used example. The important lines are 2-3.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking to get resources kinda in a HAL+JSON seriazliation format it seems, although you've said "links" and not "_links".  What you are getting them as is the Spring-HATEOAS default.  You need to use @EnableHypermedia(HAL).  Also you should have application/hal+json in your Accept header, and possibly your produces param of your @RequestMapping attribute.